# Outstanding car bill, and I am primary but have not driven it for 2 years

Tags: car

I got a 2013 Dodge Avenger with an ex that I am not with anymore. She has the car and is 2nd on the car. She did register the car in her name but has a $1100.00 bill that came to me. What can I do? I just don't want her to have this car anymore.

Comment: What do you mean "is 2nd on the car"? Is the title in both your names?  IS the bill for a loan payment? Whose name is on the loan?

Comment: The loan company probably isn't interested in the details of your personal life. If you willingly signed your name to a loan contract then you're obligated to make payments (or ensure they are made) or face the consequences.

Comment: What country and state? The car title and/or loan terms are key. If you jointly took out the loan as co-applicants, you are responsible for payments if she misses.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to contact your ex and sort it out.

If you have co-signed the loan, changes are you are equally responsible even if on party chooses not to pay, then the bank will come after the other one.

If you no longer wish to be part of the arrangement and your ex still wants the car, she will have to buy you out of the car and become fully responsible for the liability.

Answer (score 0):

What can you do?  Pay the loan or face the debt collectors.

The finance company don't care who now keeps the car, or who drives it.  There's money outstanding on the loan, and your signature on the loan form.

That's why co-signing a loan for someone else so often ends in tears.